# Join on multiple foreign key values

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

How do I fetch record from other table using multiple value in a foreign key.
e.g. I was previously story ID for subject in a new student. and I was fetching the subject name from the subject table. but now I am integrating the functionality of multiple subjects that means my ID column in student looks like: 120, 140 (which mean two subject) now how do I fetch the subject names from the other table (e.g. I want it to be shown ENGLISH, MATHS in the column when I join them).

this is my current **query**:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
  (SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
          t.*
   FROM
     (SELECT t.*,
             s.subject_name
      FROM STUDENT t
      LEFT JOIN SUBJECTS s ON t.subject_id=s.subject_id) t) t
WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have `ROWNUM`.

Comment: Do *not* put comma-separated values in a table column. Use a many-to-many relationship table, with one pair in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Well now you've many to many relationship between student and books. And you must change your db structure for the best practice.

Explained [here](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9922/~/understanding-and-creating-many-to-many-relationships-in-filemaker-pro)

let me explain very briefly here.

In this scenario a third table is formulated , normally called a **Junction table**. All the ids for both the tables are actually the rows of this table.

Example.

you can implement it in following way.

```
 student: student_id, first_name, last_name
 books: book_id, book_name, book_author_etc
 student_books: book_id, student_id     # the junction table
```

Example Queries:

```
 // To get all the books for a student. 

 SELECT b.book_id, name
    FROM student_books sb 
    INNER JOIN books b ON b.book_id = sb.book_id
    WHERE sc.student_id = Y
```